# Programmatically created extruded text's Z dimension returns zero

Tags: scripting, extrude, text-object, dimensions

With Blender 3.2.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 I am creating text using `bpy.data.curves.new`, `bpy.data.objects.new` and `py.context.scene.collection.objects.link` / `bpy.context.collection.objects.link` (from https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/163680/33447).

Printing the object and its dimensions (`bpy.data.objects[-1].dimensions`) property returns

> <bpy_struct, Object("Font Object") at 0x7f62e023a608> <Vector (0.4050,
> 0.4670, 0.0000)>

(`bpy.data.curves[-1].dimensions` also reports zero height)

whereas the Sidebar tells me 429,490,117 mm.

It also does not work with text created with

```
bpy.ops.object.text_add()
ob=bpy.context.object
ob.data.body = "my text"
```

However, it does work for manually created text (clear scene, add Text, extrude). Then run:

```
import bpy

# manual
last = bpy.data.objects[-1]
print(last)
print(last.dimensions)
    
font_curve = bpy.data.curves.new(type="FONT", name="Font Curve")
font_curve.body = "X"
font_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name="Font Object", object_data=font_curve)
font_obj.data.extrude = 0.01
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(font_obj)

print(font_obj)    
print(font_obj.dimensions)

bpy.ops.object.text_add()
ob=bpy.context.object
ob.data.body = "text"
ob.data.extrude = 0.01

print(ob)    
print(ob.dimensions)
```

Output:

```
<bpy_struct, Object("Text") at 0x7f62e01f4a08>
<Vector (1.8980, 0.6910, 0.0200)>
<bpy_struct, Object("Font Object") at 0x7f62bfbca608>
<Vector (0.7040, 0.6820, 0.0000)>
<bpy_struct, Object("Text.001") at 0x7f62bfbcbe08>
<Vector (1.8980, 0.6910, 0.0000)>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It works if, after setting the extrusion and linking to the Scene Collection, I use

```
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

Source: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/185962/33447

Docs:

- https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.view_layer
- https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ViewLayer.html#bpy.types.ViewLayer.update

> Update data tagged to be updated from previous access to data or operators